# getInstance - Class vs Method static

Tags: c++, static, initialization, singleton

I know that there are only realy basic guarantees about when a static variable is initialised. The most important thing (for me) that is not guaranteed is the order of initialisation of variables in different compilation units, which raised the following question.

I have always written my singleton classes like this:

```
class A {
    ...
    public:
       static std::shared_ptr<A> getInstance();
    private:
       static std::shared_ptr<A> _instance;
}
== A.cpp ==
std::shared_ptr<A> A::getInstance() {
    if(!_instance)
       _instance = std::make_shared<A>();
    return _instance;
}
```

However as far as I understand this does not guarantee that instance is already initialized (and therefore calling operator bool is valid) if I call this function in the constructor of any other static Object (which might in some rare case happen before main starts execution).

My new idea is the following:

```
 class A {
    ...
    public:
       static std::shared_ptr<A> getInstance();
}
== A.cpp ==
A& A::getInstance() {
    static std::shared_ptr<A> _instance = std::make_shared<A>();
    return _instance;
}
```

Which in my opinion is not just cleaner but also better code, because now I have a guaranteed order of initialisation.

Are my assumptions correct ?

Comment: Since you know that `_instance` is guaranteed to be initialized when `getInstance` is first called, why do you still need the `if` statement?

Comment: Because _instance does not hold a value. Default initialising a std::shared_ptr stores a nullpointer in it.

Comment: If so, why not initialize the `shared_ptr` with `new A` right away?

Comment: Yes you're right, initializing it with a new A would work. I did not think about this. But there is an even better way: Initializing with std::make_shared, which gives both shorter code and all advantages of make_shared. I have changed my example.

Comment: You are right! I definitely did not know that `make_shared` was more efficient than simply constructing with `new`. Thanks!

Comment: Well make_shared was added exactly for this reason. There is also allocate_shared which does the same as make_shared but supports custom allocators.

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much for making that clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `_instance` is guaranteed to be initialized before the first call to `getInstance()` (provided that they are defined in the same translation unit)

From the Standard ***3.6.2-4 Initialization of non-local variables***:

> It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a non-local variable with static storage
>   duration is done before the first statement of main. If the initialization is deferred to some point in time
>   after the first statement of main, it shall occur before the first odr-use (3.2) of any function or variable
>   defined in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized.35